# Guest User access to External Credentials

Tags: namedcredentials, external-services

I'm trying to make a callout from an unauthenticated experience page using an External Credential but I get this error.

> The callout couldn't access the endpoint. You might not have the
> required permissions, or the named credential might not exist.

Callout works fine from within Salesforce and I believe the issue is that the guest user doesn't have access to the **User External Credentials** object.

Is there anyway to give the guest user access to this object or is there another way to allow guest users to use External Credentials?

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue. No problems accessing the External and Named credential when a user has been logged in. We have need to be able to call an API (custom implementing of a One-Time Pin passwordless login) but this prevents us from being able to do so easily.

Comment: I have posted a request on the Salesforce Ideas site: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Ml2ygUAB/ability-for-guest-profile-to-access-named-external-credentials

Answer (score 1):

You can grant the guest user access for the external credentials, as it's stated in this [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_named_credentials_guestuser.htm&release=246&type=5).

However, what's not stated there is that for guest users you can only have named principal access (which is common sense as you would need to auth the guest user if you go with Per User. This way it would go through admin's auth.)